# Pyspark JSON array of objects into columns

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Im ingesting JSON files into spark and i have come across an object as below in the nested JSON from the file

```json
"data": {
  "key1" :"v1" 
  "key2" : [
     {"nk1" :"nv1"}, 
     {"nk2" :"nv2" }, 
     {"nk3" :"nv3" } 
  ] 
}
```

After reading it in spark, it is changing into below format:

```json
"data": {
  "key1" :"v1" 
  "key2" : [
     {"nk1" :"nv1", "nk2" :null, "nk3" :null}, 
     {"nk1" :null, "nk2" :"nv2", "nk3" :null}, 
     {"nk1" :null, "nk2" :null, "nk3" :"nv3"} 
  ] 
}
```

I need them as columns in the spark dataframe

| "key1" | "nk1" | "nk2" | "nk3" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "v1" | "kv1" | "kv2" | "kv3" |

Please help me with any solution for this. I'm thinking to convert this to string and use regex. Is there any better solution?

Comment: Where did "key2" go in your dataframe? Have you tried using an explode() function on the array?

Answer (score 1):

You can explode the array and pivot key2:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select(
    F.col('data.key1').alias('key1'), 
    F.explode('data.key2').alias('key2')
).select(
    'key1', 
    F.map_keys('key2')[0].alias('key'), 
    F.map_values('key2')[0].alias('val')
).groupBy('key1').pivot('key').agg(F.first('val'))

df2.show()
+----+---+---+---+
|key1|nk1|nk2|nk3|
+----+---+---+---+
|  v1|nv1|nv2|nv3|
+----+---+---+---+
```